# how set default value of db in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model

i was wondering to set default value when we type command for model, i.e

rails g model admin user:string password:string

how i can set default value to user and pass "admin"

something like.

rails g model admin user:string default:"admin" password:string default:"admin"

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In your migration file, e.g.

```
t.decimal :bounties, :precision => 8, :scale => 2, :default => 0
```

OR set a callback

```
before_create :set_admin

def set_admin
  self.role = "admin"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi one way is in migration file set default value by providing default hash and then migrate. or you can override new methods or if you want to create one admin user for application you can put into seed data.